# Cannot resolve symbol 'JsonException' - Json Simple import problem

Tags: java, json

I want to use Json simple in my project, however I can't get it to work. I tried versions 1.1.0, 3.1.0, 3.1.3, 4.0.0 and every time I do import com.github.cliftonlabs.json_simple.JsonException; I have error Cannot resolve symbol 'JsonException' I use InteliJ, every time I tried a version I went to File> Project Structure and added .jar file. Then I add dependecy compile group: 'com.github.cliftonlabs', name: 'json-simple', version: '3.1.0' into my build.gradle. The error repeats every time. How do I fix this?

Comment: As per webpage *If you've used a version before version 3.0.0 and do not wish to upgrade yet: use version 2.3.1 for the latest backwards compatible version to upgrade 1.* and 2.* code gradually to 3.* style code. Once you're ready to upgrade to 3.* all you need to do is replace import packages with com.github.cliftonlabs.json_simple and replace DeserializationException with JsonException and you'll be good to go.*  But why not use version 4?

Answer (score 0):

I managed to fix the issue, I used
`implementation 'com.github.cliftonlabs:json-simple:4.0.0'` in build.gradle
and refreshed the gradle build